# Setting Transparent Data Encryption on Azure SQL DB using an ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to turn Transparent Data Encryption on for a SQL Azure DB using an ARM json template?  If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Template Should look like this.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "serverName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "TDETest2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the new SQL Server to create."
      }
    },
    "administratorLogin": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The admin user of the SQL Server"
      }
    },
    "administratorLoginPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The password of the admin user of the SQL Server"
      }

    },
    "databaseName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "TDETest2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the new database to create."
      }
    },
    "collation": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The database collation for governing the proper use of characters."
      }
    },
    "edition": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Basic",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Basic",
        "Standard",
        "Premium"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The type of database to create."
      }
    },
    "maxSizeBytes": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "1073741824",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The maximum size, in bytes, for the database"
      }
    },
    "requestedServiceObjectiveName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Basic",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Basic",
        "S0",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes the performance level for Edition"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "SqlServer"
      },
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "[parameters('databaseName')]",
          "type": "databases",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "Database"
          },
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('serverName')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "edition": "[parameters('edition')]",
            "collation": "[parameters('collation')]",
            "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('maxSizeBytes')]",
            "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('requestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
          },
          "resources":[
            {
              "name": "current",
              "type": "transparentDataEncryption",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('databaseName')]"
              ],
              "location": null,
              "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
              "properties": {
                "status": "Disabled"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "firewallrules",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('serverName')]"
          ],
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
          "properties": {
            "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
            "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "sqlSvrFqdn": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName]"
    }
  }
}
```

`transparentDataEncryption` should be a resource that belongs to an SQL database. Hence I am putting it under the resources of the database template.

However, after testing this template, I get the following error message.

```
Code    : InvalidTemplate
Message : Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/TDETest2/databases/TDETest2' cannot reference itself. Please see http://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage details.'.
```

That means Transparent Data Encryption is not supported yet in ARM Template. I have posted a feature request. Please vote [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/13376694-transparent-data-encryption-support-for-arm-templa)

> Thanks for @JeffBailey. I find out that I have made a mistake in my template, using serverName instead of databaseName in the `dependsOn` of the transparentDataEncryption. The template has been updated.

Comment: Actually, I got it to work using your template.  Your transparentDataEncryption should be dependent on [parameters('databaseName')] instead of serverName.  There is no intellisense/schema support for the resources section but at least it works!.  Thanks for your help @Jack Zeng

Comment: Thanks for Pointing it out. It's a typo to use the serverName. I will update the answer.

Comment: Even with the updated template, I still get the same error. How did you make it work, @JeffBailey?

Comment: Try setting "version": "12.0" on your server properties, right after administratorLogin.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the resource:

```
        "resources":[
        {
          "name": "current",
          "type": "transparentDataEncryption",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('databaseName')]"
          ],
          "location": null,
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
          "properties": {
            "status": "Enabled"
          }
        }
      ]
```

And the database version has to be version 12:

```
"resources": [
{
  "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "SqlServer"
  },
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
  "properties": {
    "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
    "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]",
    "version": "12.0"
  },
```

Comment: Same config, still getting conflict with error "Operation on server ___ and database ___ is in progress.  Please wait a few minutes before trying again."
And waiting doesn't help.
If you increase api version you will get internal server error (failed).

Answer (score 0):

Now encryption is on by default, you don't need to set it as enabled.